# setInt and getInt values changing Flutter

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart

I am capturing the datetime that an action is taken and setting it in SharedPreferences like so (prefs is an instance of SharedPreferences),

`prefs.setInt('last_action_date', actionDate.millisecondsSinceEpoch);`

when printing the value that is saved I get `1579117670122` (2020-01-15 11:47:50.122384)
and later accessing it through,

`prefs.getInt('last_action_date');`

but when I print the value it has become `1579109000664`(2020-01-15 09:23:20.664).

The code works as expected when the phone being used is in the same timezone as my server but when I move the phone back to PST in this case it is changing the value that was saved.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you save the date string instead of the milliseconds since epoch. Timezone's are the worst, and it is challenging to account for them. If you save as an ISO date string, though, the timezone is encoded straight into the string.
You could accomplish this with the following:

```dart
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('my-date-key', new DateTime.now().toIso8601String());
```

This will save a string like `2020-01-15T12:30-02:00` into your shared preferences, with the timezone accounted for.

Answer (score 0):

Parse this string back to a DateTime object using parse() method.

```
main(List args) {

  //DateTime myDatetime = DateTime.parse("2022-11-30 17:19:35");
  DateTime myDatetime = DateTime.parse("Datetime");
  print(myDatetime.toIso8601String());
}
```